# NodeJS: Comparing each element of an array with all other elements with an async process?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am using [Resemble.js](https://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) to compare images in my web application. 
I get an array of images(urls). I want to compare the images with every other image in the array and calculate the unique score of that image.
Eg. [url1, url2, url3, url4]
So the minimum combination will be

```
1 => 2
1 => 3
1 => 4
2 => 3
2 => 4
3 => 4
```

But i would also need to store the opposite combination values(although they would be same)
Eg. 1 => 2 will be same as 2 => 1

**Question**
How do i run the loop something like

```
 for (var i = 1; i<=arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i+1; j <=arr.length; j++) {
        console.log(i + " => " + j);
       //async operation to compare two images
    }
}
```

using the async module for Nodejs. Also not comparing two images again for their opposite combination result. instead use the already calculated score.

**EDIT**

**MODIFIED** my existing code which works very fine and gives correct results and is pretty fast too.
Is there any way i can optimize it further?

```
var arr = [ 
        {url: 'url1'}, {url:'url2'}, {url:'url3'}
    ];

    function range(length) {
        var l = [];
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if(i != j){
                    l[counter] = {
                        i: i,
                        j: j
                    };
                    counter++;  
                }

            }
        }
        return l;
    }

    var ijs = range(arr.length);
    var tempUS = 0; 
    async.each(ijs, function (ij, cb) {
            if(ij.i != ij.j && ij.i > ij.j) {
                resemble(arr[ij.i].url).compareTo(arr[ij.j].url).onComplete(function(data) {
                   console.log(data.misMatchPercentage);
                   ij.score = data.misMatchPercentage;
                   cb();
                }); 
            }
            else {
                cb();
            }

        },
        function(err){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                for(var e = 0; e <arr.length; e++) {
                    var z = 0;
                    for(var f = 0; f < ijs.length; f++) {
                        if(ijs[f].i == e) {
                            if(ijs[f].score) {
                                z = z+ parseFloat(ijs[f].score);    
                            }

                        }
                        else if(ijs[f].j == e) {
                            if(ijs[f].score) {
                                z = z+ parseFloat(ijs[f].score);    
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    console.log(e, " ======== ", z);
                    var avg = z/arr.length;
                    arr[e].uniqueScore = avg;
                }
                console.log(arr);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you store all of these async functions in an array and at the end of your loop run them with async.parallel. You then will get all the results in the callback and be able to work with all of them together

Comment: You'll need something like this http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each you can map the i and j into lists.

Comment: Show what you have tried. Hint: Use 2 (nested) async.each with `arr.slice(index)` for inner async.each

Comment: @Sangharsh i have already used two asyc loops (not slicing though) and it works very slow and i am looking to get a better way to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bring in the async module and do:

```
function range(length) {
    var l = [];
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            l[counter] = {
                i: i,
                j: j
            };
            counter++;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return l;
}

var ijs = range(arr.length);

async.each(ijs, function (ij, cb) {
    resemble(arr[ij.i])compareTo(arr[ij.j]).onComplete(function(data){
       // data; // do something with data
       cb(); // call the callback so we know we can move on
       /*
       {
          misMatchPercentage : 100, // %
          isSameDimensions: true, // or false
          getImageDataUrl: function(){}
       }
       */
    });
});
```

#### Edit

Updated my range function to exclude duplicates.

Comment: This definetly works very fast but what i need to do is calculate the unique score for 1st url with all other urls and then calculate the average of it and store.how can i add that int this single loop

Comment: Also it is comparing the images again for eg. image 1 and image 2 & then image 2 and image 1. Thanks.

Comment: 1) you can push all the result back into an results object and iterate over that. 2) well, you can modify that in the range function to suit your specific needs. I've demonstrated how to get the what you need, I'm not going to write your exact solution because this isn't a code writing service...

Comment: Hi. I have done and edited my code with your help. I just wanted to get a way to optimize the code. My new code works fine with your help. I would be thankful if you can see whether i can optimize it further.

Comment: @Indian_DEVELOPER updated my answer so the range function doesn't duplicate images

Comment: Thanks. That really helped.